# Cannot Establish RMI connection between services in istio

Tags: kubernetes, rmi, istio

i have a kubernetes cluster where istio is deployed with a bunch of services, but i can't seem to establish a communication between two particular pods using RMI protocol, both pods have an istio sidecar injected.

this is the kubernetes services :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-1
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: rmi-port
    port: 10022
    targetPort: 10022
    appProtocol: tcp
  selector:
    app: svc-1
  type: ClusterIP
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-2
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: rmi-port
    port: 10021
    targetPort: 10021
    appProtocol: tcp
  selector:
    app: svc-2
  type: ClusterIP
```

in this example service-2 is the initiator of the request and tries to connect to service-1 on port 10022, but i always get the following error :

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset - java.rmi.ConnectIOException : error during JRMP connection establishment
```

it should be mentioned that the communication occurs if i tried to remove the envoy proxy from the pod starting the request.
i also noticed that the envoy proxy logs generate "BlackHoleCluster" whenever i make the rmi request to service-1
[envoy proxy logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izET8.png)

Update :
[Receiving RMI service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2sX0.png)
[Initiator service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2s9g.png)

i don't really know the nitty gritty of how the call happen in the source code but basically the initiator service call the rmi service using a url in this format : rmi://rmi-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:10022/rmi-service

Comment: i hope the issue is clear for you, I feel like I'm at a dead end :(

Comment: can you try changing the service definition as "- name: tcp-rmi1 protocol: TCP" with port and targetPort.  Also same for service 2 "- name: tcp-rmi2 protocol: TCP" with port and targetPort.  For some details of JMRP support in istion are discussed in following link https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15293

Comment: Hello @NatarajMedayhal unfortunately, i still get the same error, i think the envoy proxy is the one that mess with the communication

Comment: can you share modified service definition, deployment definition and details of how the rmi call is happening

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal i updated my post with service definitions, Thanks

Comment: trust both service 1 and service 2 definition are changed.  the screenshot attached i could see only service 2 definition is changed and rmi url its seen first rmi service is invoked.  also ensure correct rmi url is used in application while invoking.   for ex: rmi://rmi-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:10022/service-1